# How to use carousel View in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement Images carousel View as per the below image.
[image]

I want to display multiple images using carousel view with highlighted dots when user scroll the images (Highlight the respective dot below the image) in Xamarin IOS.

I tried with iCarousel - Xamarin Component ( iCarousel Link ) to display images with dots. Here i am able to display the images in carousel view. Can any one suggest me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UIPageControl underneath the iCarousel view:

```
UIPageControl pageControl = new UIPageControl(frame));
pageControl.Pages = carousel.NumberOfItems;
pageControl.CurrentPage = carousel.CurrentItemIndex;
// For some reason I needed to set the back ground color 
// for ValueChanged event to fire if you want pages to 
// change when the UIPageControl is tapped.
pageControl.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black; 
View.AddSubview(pageControl);
```

Then handle the carousel.ScrollEnd event:

```
carousel.ScrollEnd += (sender, e) =>
{
    pageControl.CurrentPage = carousel.CurrentItemIndex;
};
```

And if you want to be able to change the page by tapping the UIPageControl:

```
pageControl.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    carousel.CurrentItemIndex = pageControl.CurrentPage;
};
```

With a UIPageControl, you tap on the left or right of the control to go to the previous or next page, but you can't go to a specific page by clicking a dot. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/index.html

I added the iCarousel Component sample with the UIPageControl added here: https://github.com/jgold6/XamarinSupportSamples/tree/master/iOS-iCarouselWithPageControl